# select multiple song id from MediaStore.Audio.Media

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have created a `getContentResolver().query` using the follwing

```
 uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            String projection[] = { android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.COMPOSER,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID };
                    String selection1 = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID + "=?" ;
                    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {"" + 19};
                    cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                    selection1, selectionArgs, null);
                    songs = new ArrayList<String>();
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) { 
                    songs.add(cursor.getString(1));
```

This works perfectly fine for selecting single song , however when I try to select multiple songs using

```
String selection1 = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID + "IN(?,?)";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {"" + 12,"" + 19};
```

This query fails .

Is there a proper way to select multiple songs , what is wrong with the above query.
please explain the changes needed to be made.

Comment: add " " (space) before "IN"

Comment: Thank you very much. @pskink

Comment: how can we select multiple songs from a particular id , i have selected all songs from an album id using selectionargs as android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID, now as above code how can we use both multiple id's of songs and album id in selectionargs simultaneoulsy

Comment: have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: i just want to select multiple songs from a particular album, not all the songs but a few songs how can that be done?

Comment: the same: MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID is unique to all of your songs, in other words there cannot be two identical _IDs in the MediaStore.Audio.Media table

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with your query using the **IN** operator. I suspect the query with IN has quirks and limitations. I did not use it however. Try just using the **OR** operator instead.
Example:

```
String selection1 = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID + "=12" + " OR " + MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID + "=19";
```

And of course not use `selectionArgs` as the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Another good try is using **raw query** instead, documentation @ [SQL rawQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20android.os.CancellationSignal)). With a raw query, you can use the **IN** operator, and I think it's a good idea for simplifying queries. I should use it next time.

Thanks for this question!